# How to select specific dictionaries (with no key names) from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am currently working with road networks and followed [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227909/from-shapefile-to-python-networkx) that explained exactly what I was looking for.

I, however, am facing a problem. I tried running the script on a small part of my domain and came across the error shown bellow.

```
NetworkXError: Edge tuple (35,) must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple.
```

After checking every variable I was working with, I found out that the problems is from the `l = [set(x) for x in G.edges()]`

I basically have a list of dictionaries that contain two set of coordinates (which represent the start and the end points of each roads of my domain) but some of the roads only have one set of coordinates in the dictionary.

Here's a simplified version of what I get when I `print(l)`:

```
[{(2.455183, 48.7774425), (2.4551873, 48.7776523)},
{(2.4574735, 48.7736999), (2.4577528, 48.7738954)},
{(2.4574735, 48.7736999)},
{(2.4577528, 48.7738954), (2.4578287, 48.7723847)},
{(2.4585674, 48.7823935), (2.4586793, 48.7825114)}]
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to select the dictionaries that only have one set of coordinates and either *duplicate it inside the dictionary* (so instead of having `{(2.4574735, 48.7736999)},` I would have `{(2.4574735, 48.7736999), (2.4574735, 48.7736999)}`) or *delete them* if the previous proposition is not doable.

I found several ways of selecting dictionaries in a list based on their key names but I don't have any keys in mine so nothing I tried worked so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no dictionaries in this code to begin with because `set(x)` constructs a _set_.

Comment: Change `set(x)` to `list(x)`. `set`s don't have duplicates. Period.

Comment: you can't duplicate within a set, but you can easily filter `[item for item in lst if len(item) > 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not dictionaries. These are [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). And your first requirement is not possible, as sets can not contain duplicate entries. So you can just check the lengths of the sets, and skip the ones that are less than length 2. So something like this:

```
l = [set(x) for x in G.edges() if len(set(x))>1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it is working perfectly fine. I am relatively new to python and didn't know about sets...

Comment: I figured. That is why I included the link to sets documentation. Go through it. It is a relatively lesser-known data structure in Python as compared to Lists, Tuples and Dictionaries. Beginner Tutorials do not cover sets. But sets are extremely useful in certain situations, especially in case of handling duplicate data.